# how to match a character unless it is part of a specific string with regex

Tags: regex

Don't know how to explain this, so an example:

```
xx_xx -> matches because of the underscore -> .*_.*

xx_t_xx -> dont want this to match as _t_ is an exception I want to ignore

xx_t_xx_xx -> matches as there is an underscore that is not part of the string _t_

xx_t_xx_t_xx -> no match

_t_ -> no match

_ -> match

_t__ -> match
```

So match underscores unless it is part of the string `_t_`

Can that be done with regex?

Comment: what is the regex that you are using now ? is it .*_.* ?

Comment: I'm not, I have not been able to do it

Comment: So you want to match an underscore unless it is preceded or followed by `t`? Or is that just an example?

Comment: No I want to exclude that specific string of characters

Comment: what `xx_t_xx_t_xx` would give?

Comment: no match as all underscores are part of the excluded string

Comment: should you return anything? or you just need to check for presence of `_t_`?

Comment: Just need to match or not match as described in my now 7 examples

Comment: `_t__t_t_` matches or not?

Comment: Good question, but in my case will not be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Done, checked all your conditions. works fine
Try this, it accepts any single character. 
This will definitely work for you

```
^([^_]|(_t_))*_([^_]|(_t_))*$
```

Answer (score 2):

okay

use this : `^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$`

this will only match one underscore

i.e it will match `xx_xx` but not `xx_t_xx`

try this in your console :

```
var str = "xx_xx";
var res = /^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$/.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

and yes one more thing . `LEARN REGEX` its very helpful. you will like to start from regexone

Comment: This doesn't work if there is an underscore and the excluded text,  I have edited my question to include that example as well

Answer (score 1):

If your language supports negative lookbehind and negative lookahead, you can use `(?<!_t)_(?!t_)` regex. Basically you search for `_` not preceded by `_t` and not followed by `t_`

Comment: This looked promising, but unfortunately not supported in javascript, but worth an up tick